# Chrome Dev Tools show Resourecs in largesize and content downloaded in very small size

Tags: rest, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In my application i am making an REST call which is giving approximately 7mb of Data but when i see in chrome Devtools i see the resources of around 50mb as in this screenshot [devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeuHy.png) is also loading to my browser, which is affecting the performance of application, can you please let us know what exactly is this resources are??

Comment: You have your 7MB on the left of the 50mb in your screenshot.The 50mb part if the size of the app itself if I'm not mistaken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`48.9 MB resources` refers to the size of all the page's resources after they have been decompressed. `7.4 MB transferred` is the amount of data that was downloaded over the network. Your page is downloading 7.4 MB of data, not 48.9 MB.

Think of it like this:

- 7.4 MB of compressed data is downloaded
- The browser decompresses all of that data
- The uncompressed size of *that same data* is 48.9 MB

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference#total-size